# Es posible insertar comentarios dentro de los paréntesis cuando instanciamos una clase

Tags: javascript

He visto el siguiente código, y me preguntaba qué es "**map**" porque viendo el resto del código no encontré nada que hiciera uso de ello.

```js
let app = new App("map", 10, 10, 50);
app.map.set(10, 4, 2);
```

Podría alguien decirme si es un comentario o hace referencia a algo más o es un elemento más dentro de los parámetros que podemos o no utilizar más adelante.

Gracias!

Agrego algo más de información
Esta es la clase a la que hace referencias

```js
class App {
    constructor( canvas,sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase) {
        this.map = new Maps(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase);
        this.players = [];
    }
```

Y aquí está el constructor de la clase map

```js
class Maps {
    constructor(canvas, sizeX, sizeY, sizeCase){
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas);
        this.canvas.width = sizeCase * sizeX;
        this.canvas.height = sizeCase * sizeY;
        this.size = {x: sizeX, y: sizeY, case: sizeCase};
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.tiles = [];
        this.tileMap = new Image();
        this.tileMap.src = "img/tilemap4.png";
    }
```

Comment: Si te refieres al parámetro que recibe tu clase `App`, es simplemente eso: *un parámetro*, que en este caso es de tipo `String` y su valor es `"map"`. Tendrías que mostrar el código de la clase o al menos el constructor de la misma para saber de qué manera es usado por tu instancia. Por otro lado, si te refieres al atributo `map` de tu clase, igualmente necesitamos ver el código de dicho atributo, el cual al parecer tiene un método `set`. Saludos

Comment: @RimuruTempest Faltarían los métodos, lo que no veo claro es cómo se usa el parámetro 'map' ya que luego en la clase map no veo su uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El parámetro `**maps**` de acuerdo a tu propio código es:

- El el primer argumento del método contructor directamente relacionado con la propiedad `canvas`
- Luego dentro del método constructor se iguala con el siguiente valor:

Código:

```
 this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas);
```

Lo que hace es que obtiene el tag canvas de tu HTML que por lo que noto tiene un id `map`

Entonces cuando realizas la instancia espera obtener un `id` que le pasará al método `getElementById` para leer el tag de dibujo en 2d canvas.

Entonces

`map` es el id el cual requiere el método constructor de la clase para que al momento de hacer la instancia pueda leer el contexto del área de dibujo